# Asymmetric columns - Picking latest given value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Version Used: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, SQL Server 2008

I'm facing a frustrating issue that is caused by asymmetric columns. Basically, I want to calculate the effects of a discount on given spot prices. Both are set up as indexes *in the same table* **pricevalues**. Spot prices are given 5 days á week, while discounts are only stated on the day they were updated. So, for example:

**pricevalues(priceindex, price, pricedate)**

```
     PRICEINDEX             PRICE            PRICEDATE              
-------------------- ------------------ ------------------
DISCOUNT_INDEX_ID   |       15.5       |    2013-02-26
DISCOUNT_INDEX_ID   |       10.5       |    2013-04-05
DISCOUNT_INDEX_ID   |       16.0       |    2013-07-10
SPOT_INDEX_ID       |       356.5      |    2013-07-22
SPOT_INDEX_ID       |       355.0      |    2013-07-23
SPOT_INDEX_ID       |       354.6      |    2013-07-24
SPOT_INDEX_ID       |       357.0      |    2013-07-25
SPOT_INDEX_ID       |       358.5      |    2013-07-26
```

How would I best go about calculating the difference between PRICE's for SPOT_INDEX_ID and DISCOUNT_INDEX_ID on all dates that SPOT_INDEX_ID is given, if the latest given (relative to the PRICEDATE of the spot price) discount PRICE is to be used?

For example, the discount on a spot on 2013-07-22 is **16.0** (2013-07-10), while the discount on a spot on 2013-05-15 is **10.5** (2013-04-05) and the discount on a spot on 2013-03-03 is **15.5** (2013-02-26)

I only know how to do it when the PRICEDATE's match for both DISCOUNT_INDEX_ID and SPOT_INDEX_ID, so:

```
SELECT 
(pv1.price - pv2.price) AS 'Total Price',
pv1.price AS 'Spot Price',
pv2.price AS 'Discount'
FROM 
pricevalues pv1, pricevalues pv2
WHERE
pv1.priceindex = 'SPOT_INDEX_ID' AND 
pv1.pricedate = pv2.pricedate AND
pv2.priceindex = 'DISCOUNT_INDEX_ID'
```

This is of course not possible whith these huge gaps in the discount index, so when the dates do not match, how do I instead get the value of the *latest given* discount?

EDIT: I would like the output to look like the following:

```
    PRICEDATE        SPOT_INDEX         DISCOUNT_INDEX      SPOT_PRICE      
---------------- ------------------- --------------------- -----------   --->>>
   2013-07-26   |   SPOT_INDEX_ID   |  DISCOUNT_INDEX_ID  |   358.5   |

 DISCOUNT_PRICE       TOTAL_PRICE             
---------------- -------------------
      16.0      |       342.5       |
```

Comment: Could you show a sample of the output you'd like to be returned from this query?  Also, are there daily entries for spot index?

Comment: I've added a sample output. New entries are added to the spot index 5 days of the week (Mon-Fri). Entries to the discount index are added irregularly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with a combination of FETCHES in SQL and processing in Excel where I also took care of the gaps in the discount index.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the Discount price in a variable for a given date and then use it in the main query. here is the sample:

```
Declare @Discount_Price money
select Max(pricedate),@Discount_Price=Price from pricevalues where PriceIndex='DISCOUNT_INDEX_ID' group by Price having Price=Max(PriceDate)    
SELECT 
    (pv1.price - @Discount_Price) AS PriceDiff,
    pv1.price AS 'Spot Price',
    @Discount_Price AS 'Discount'
FROM 
    pricevalues pv1 
WHERE
    pv1.priceindex = 'SPOT_INDEX_ID'
```

Comment: While this works for the absolute latest given discount, I need to be able to find the latest discount *relative* to the spot. If I have a spot on 2013-03-01, a discount on 2013-03-02 is **invalid** since it isn't the latest relative to the spot. On the other hand, a discount stated on 2013-02-29 would be valid - if, of course, there are no other discounts even closer to 2013-03-01 (from the past).

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to return one record this will work:

```
DECLARE @date DATE = GETDATE()
SELECT TOP 1 a.PRICEDATE, b.PRICE 'Spot', a.PRICE 'Discount', b.Price - a.Price 'Total'
FROM #Table1 a
JOIN (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PRICEINDEX ORDER BY PRICEDATE DESC)'RowRank'
      FROM #Table1
      WHERE PRICEINDEX = 'SPOT_INDEX_ID'
          AND PRICEDATE <= @date
      )b         
  ON b.RowRank = 1
WHERE a.PRICEINDEX = 'DISCOUNT_INDEX_ID'
       AND a.PRICEDATE <= @date 
ORDER BY a.PRICEDATE DESC
```

Change `GETDATE()` to whatever your inquiry date is.

I wasn't sure what you wanted for `PRICEDATE`, perhaps that should be `b.PRICEDATE`, or maybe just `@date`?

Comment: Is there a way to modify this so it is a function of a date range and returns a table? Say if I wanted the TOTAL PRICE for all dates 2012-2013.